# Add hours to time series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got this following time series[1] which have the timezone in UTC, since my timezone is GMT+1 i would like to add 1 hours to all this time. I try different solutions (like convert it to datetime and add a timedelta) but none of that solutions works. How can i solve this problem, I've been working on it all day but can't find a working solution.

[1]:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv( "streaming_history_New1.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", sep = ';') 

dfNew = pd.DataFrame(df.end_time.str.split(' ',1).tolist(),columns = ['date','time']

print(dfNew['time'])

0       15:49
1       15:53
2       15:54
3       16:41
4       16:54
 ....
2862    19:16
2863    19:19
2864    19:22
2865    19:24
2866    19:27
Name: time, Length: 2867, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first cast the column `time` to a `datetime` object and then perform `pd.Timedelta` increment.

Try this:

```py
from datetime import datetime

d['time_p'] = (d['time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%H:%M")) + pd.Timedelta("1 hour")).apply(lambda y: datetime.strftime(y, "%H:%M"))
```

Column `time_p` is your expected time column incremented by `1 hour`

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should just work like

```
series + pd.Timedelta('1 hour')
```

where `series` is your pandas series data

Comment: i've got the following error unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timedelta' and 'str'

Comment: To me that would suggest that your series variable (which I'll call `x`) has been overwritten with a string at some point. You could check this by typing `print(type(x))` just above where you try to add the time delta

Comment: Afaq solve my problem, thank you dan